# What is the radius of convergence of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(4+\left(-1\right)^n\right)^nx^n$

Tags: calculus, power-series

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(4+\left(-1\right)^n\right)^nx^n$$

I was asked to find the radius of the convergence, but the Power-Series diverges, so I'm a bit confused.

We tried Cauchy-Hadamard and got 1/5 as the answer but weren't sure about it.

Comment: What do you mean? There are certainly values of $x$ for which the power series does *not* diverge.

Comment: And what test would one use to prove that? I tried using Cauchy-Adamer (probably spelled it wrong) and couldn't "solve it".

Comment: Well, for starters, a power series **always** converges at its center, so at $x = 0$ here (this should be obvious - if not, write out terms until it is). It should also be easy for you to show that if $|x| < 1/5$ the series converges by comparison to a geometric series.

Comment: Also, you should [edit] your attempt into the body of the question - had you included the fact that you tried Cauchy-Hadamard and got $1/5$, this would have been a simple yes/no verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plugging into Cauchy-Hadamard:$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(4+(-1)^n)^n} =\limsup_{n\to\infty}(4+(-1)^n)=5$$

Comment: Indeed, me and my friend weren't sure about it, thanks for resolving the issue. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.